# Flask Server in Python ruining looks

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to render my website inside of flask as I made a backend inside of it.

I've used both of the following codes:

```
    def TestDir():
        return render_template('Index/index.html')
```

and

```
    def HomeDir():
        return(open('Templates/Index/index.html').read())
```

but it shows all glitchy: https://i.1nch.dev/cdn/0pPwq1kDY2Oc9CMM.gif

But on my pc it shows normal: https://i.1nch.dev/cdn/l3LnfmUzyad78Nl5.gif

Comment: What is the folder structure for your app? more specifically the css/js files

Comment: My index is in `Templates/Index/index.html` The css is in `Templates/Index/style.css` and the js is in `Templates/Index/app.js` and so on @Stoobish

Comment: This glitchiness can be caused by a number of things, including slow loading of images, but it's likely a CSS issue that you're not seeing locally because local is so fast. You have a few options. One is to try stripping this down to the smallest possible example that demonstrates the problem. That exercise is often enough to point to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a static folder setup for your css and js files unless you override it when you initialize Flask.

Your app directory should look something like this:

```
/app
    - app_runner.py
    /templates
        /Index
        - Index.html
    /static
        /css
            - style.css
```

To access the css file in your html use something like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}">`